# How to pass values from MapOverlay

Tags: java, android

I want to pass the values from *MapOverlay* class to another class. I tried to use an Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherClass.class);
i.putExtra("value1", x1);
i.putExtra("value2", y1);
startActivity(i);
```

but Eclipse alerts me "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MapOverlay" so I can't use this method to pass the values. Please advise me on how I should do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to Use GetSet method for this -

In your Mapoverlay class -

```
GetSet gs = new GetSet();
gs.setFname(value1,value2);
```

**Getset.java**

```
public class GetSet 
{
public static String fName[];
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void setFname(String value1, String value2)
{
    fName[] = new String[2];
    fName[1] = value1;
    fName[2] = value2;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public String[] getfName()
{
    return this.fName;
}
}
```

And, whereever you need that values, just get like below code -

```
GetSet gs = new GetSet();
resultofoverlay = gs.getFname();
```

Here, `resultofoverlay` is a string array. Try to declare this as global.